# convert price on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My products price is based on USD , but i want change USD to IRR with a Conversion Rate (1 USD = 3500 IRR) in shop and checkout . I found this code but it works only for product veiw and when i click on cart or checkout price change to USD .

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wpa83367_price_html', 100, 2 );
function wpa83367_price_html( $price, $product ){
    $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
    $toman = 3500;
    $total = $price * $toman . ' ' . 'تومان';
    return $total;
}
```

Comment: what currency is this?

Comment: @Reigel iranian money currency